# Still don't get how to mock an imported library - Python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I've looked around but still don't get how to mock a library used inside a function and assert that its been called properly.

```
a.py

import win32clipboard

def copy():

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('dummy')
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

test_a.py

```
import a
import pytest

def test_copy():

    # Mock win32clipboard somehow
    # Run a.copy()

    # assert mock win32clipboard.call_count == 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your approach.

`win32clipboard` is a library, with some classes and methods. You must mock every class from this library you want to use (`OpenClipboard`, `EmptyClipboard`, `SetClipboardText` and `CloseClipboard`)

```
import a
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('win32clipboard.OpenClipboard')
@patch('win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard')
@patch('win32clipboard.SetClipboardText')
@patch('win32clipboard.CloseClipboard')
def test_copy(mock_close, mock_set, mock_empty, mock_open):
    a.copy()

    assert mock_close.called
    assert mock_set.called
    assert mock_empty.called
    assert mock_open.called
```

Comment: I actually found out the answer to my own question here some time ago already but my post got deleted for not clarifying enough, apparently. I wasn't even aware since I never came back to check this thread but thanks for giving a perfect example (using decorators) for others to see how its done @MauroBaraldi!